# DX11 swap chain only showing first frame. Flips between it and a black image

Tags: windows, directx, windows-8, directx-11

When I run my 3d scene, it only renders the first frame and then flips between it and a black screen, causing lots of flicker. I think it's my swap chain that's not set up correctly, but I don't really know.

Here's my code to set it up. It's pretty much copied from an Microsoft example.

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 sd = {0};
sd.Width = 0;                           
sd.Height = 0;
sd.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM; 
sd.Stereo = false; 
sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                
sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
sd.BufferCount = 2;                     
sd.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;
sd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
sd.Flags = 0;

CoreWindow^ window =  reinterpret_cast<CoreWindow^>(mSystem->GetIWindow());
hr = pIDXGIFactory->CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow(mD3DDevice,  reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(window), &sd, NULL, &mSwapChain);
EA_ASSERT(SUCCEEDED( hr ));
```

And the present code:

```
DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS  presentParameters = {0};
HRESULT hr = mSwapChain->Present1(0, 0, &presentParameters);
```

Seems to me pretty straighforward, so I don't really get why it's not working.

The scene is running all the time. The update function gets run every frame.

Also, if I check the render in PIX, everything is fine. I get what I expect the render to be. It just doesn't appear on screen.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't calling OMSetRenderTargets on my device context every frame. Now it works.

Comment: While porting from D3D11 to D3D11_3 got the flickering issue. Solved after adding your solution. Does anyone have a clue why OMSetRenderTargets needs to be called for every frame in D3D11_3

Comment: @RaviGanesh: The documentation for [Present1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/DXGI1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgiswapchain1-present1) says: "For flip presentation model swap chains that you create with the DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL value set, a successful presentation results in an unbind of back buffer 0 from the graphics pipeline."